# HCatalog: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

I am trying to read and write the data using HCatalog, I read that the following error I am getting is because of version mismatch, tried changing the versions of hive and hadoop, but no luck yet.
Any help highly appreciated.

Info:

```
INFO: output schema explicitly set for writing:groupname:org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatFieldSchema@17c565b8[fieldName=groupname,comment=<null>,type=string,category=PRIMITIVE],id:org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatFieldSchema@20991f39[fieldName=id,comment=<null>,type=int,category=PRIMITIVE]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatBaseOutputFormat.getOutputFormat(HCatBaseOutputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatBaseOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(HCatBaseOutputFormat.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at test.App.run(App.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at test.App.main(App.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Following are the classpath variables: 
HADOOP_HOME = /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop-2.6.0 
HIVE_HOME = /usr/local/Cellar/apache-hive-1.1.0

And in POM, these are the dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <hadoop.version>2.6.0</hadoop.version>
      <hcatalog.version>1.1.0</hcatalog.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
      <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-hcatalog-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hcatalog.version}</version>
      <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-archives</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-tests</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
Downloaded source code of hive 1.1.0, built locally using this command

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist -DskipTests
```

and used the formed binary, it started working. 
Thanks.